# Combining INSERT SELECT and VARIABLES

Tags: mysql, variables, select, insert

I have two table  `users_new` and `users_old` with some count of rows.
I would like to insert data from `users_old` to `users_new` by using `insert select`.

Table `users_old` has one field `name`, which contains first name and last name.
Table `users_new` must have two fields, first name (`name`)and last name (`surname`).

I don't know how combine them. Any advice?

```
SET @str="";
SET @firstName="";
SET @lastName="";

INSERT INTO users_new  (name, surname)
VALUES(
    SELECT @firstName,@lastName;
    @str=select name
        FROM  users_old  
SET @firstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, ' ', 1);
SET @lastName=LTRIM(REPLACE(@str, @firstName, ''))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the splitting criterion is the space, as implied by the sql code posted, then you can use a simple `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO users_new (name, surname)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1)
FROM users_old
```

The last name is selected by a second call to [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index): this one gets the *second part* of the `name` field, because of the`-1` argument.

Comment: It's only going to work, if all the names are consists of a last and a first name. If you only got one word for a name, it will be duplicated in both cols, and if you have a middle name in the mix, the last name will be lost.